# Ng-Click Within Handlebars.JS Template Won't Fire

Tags: angularjs, handlebars.js

so I am building an application and at first I was introduced to handlebars.js for HTML templating using JSON from the server, which is great.

But I think I may have conceptually missed some things, because I understand Angular JS also has templating functionality? Should these technologies not be used together?

Anyway, because I started with handlebars.js first, I have my template in handlebars and included in the template is an `ng-click` which of course doesn't fire because Angular doesn't know about it and it isn't compiled in Angular.

Is there a way to tell Angular about this `ng-click` in the handlebars template once I run something like:

```
var source   = $("#newPostTemplate").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
$("#subBoxone").append(template(theData));
```

Or should I just do an Angular template? I don't know anything about templating in Angular though so it would be nice to carry on with my handlebars.js implementation and just have the `ng-click` from that template work. How do I do that?

This is the part of the template with the `ng-click`:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg thoughtButton" ng-click="pollData()">Submit Additional Comment!</button>
```

I could attach the ng-click to another element higher up in the DOM hierarchy and use `$event` to figure out if it is the right one I think, but I would prefer to tap into this generated `ng-click` directly.

Thank you, and I happy to provide more information if necessary!

Answer (score 0):

You can keep Handlebars for the templating part but you'll need to add a directive that's responsible for doing the Handlebars templating and then compiling it.

To compile a block of HTML you could have a directive with a `template` / `compile` function or manually compile it yourself `link` function with `$compile`. I've never used Handlebars before so you may need to experiment a bit, but an example would be something like:

```
angular.module('handlebarsTemplate', [])
  .directive('handlebarsTemplate', function() {
    return {
      ...
      template: function(tElem, tAttrs) {
        var html = tElem.html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(html);
        return template;
      }
      ...
    };
  });
```

So wherever you have your Handlebars template, you just need to wrap it in this directive and it should get compiled with Angular with your compiled Handlebars template.